# Wait for N items in channel before executing sequentially

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

So I am very new to go! But I had this idea about something I wanted to try.

I would like to have a go routine that accepts strings from a channel but only after it has received N strings should it execute on them.

I looked around for similar questions or cases but I only found ones where the idea was to execute several routines in parallel and wait to aggregate the result.

I though about the idea of creating an array and just pass it to a routine where the length was sufficient. However I want to keep a certain separation of concerns and control this on the receiving end.

My questions are.

1. Is this bad practice for some reason?
2. Is there a better way to do this, what is it?

   ```
   func main() {
       ch := make(chan string)
       go func() {
           tasks := []string{}
           for {
               tasks = append(tasks,<- ch)

               if len(tasks) < 3 {
                   fmt.Println("Queue still to small")
               }
               if len(tasks) > 3 {
                   for i := 0; i < len(tasks); i++ {
                       fmt.Println(tasks[i])
                   }
               }
           }
       }()

       ch <- "Msg 1"
       time.Sleep(time.Second)
       ch <- "Msg 2"
       time.Sleep(time.Second)
       ch <- "Msg 3"
       time.Sleep(time.Second)
       ch <- "Msg 4"
       time.Sleep(time.Second)
   }
   ```

Edit for simpler more accurate example.

Comment: I don't know that it's bad practice but it's highly unusual and looks like an XY Problem. What are you actually trying to do with this - what problem are you solving?

Comment: I'm attempting to acumulate data for a "sendmany" rpc call to a bitcoin core node. Now I'm thinking that this could be easier with a chan of strings than funcs... The idea is, if i have enough requests, send them as one payment to several people and I can pay a lower fee. [bitcoin core ref.](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.16.0/rpc/wallet/sendmany/)

Comment: 1) Durable storage may be more appropriate for this scenario.  The application will lose payments if the application exits (possibly due to a crash).  2) To avoid adding arbitrarily large amount of latency, you may want to chunk by time rather than by count. 3) Ignoring these possible issues with your scenario, the code is OK.

Comment: @ThunderCat Thanks! Feels like a well needed sanity check and great advice!

Comment: I would like to say this. The code I added below is in production, running v fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on a few comments, it looks like what you are looking for is some form of batching.

Batching has a few scenarios when you would want to take the batch and send it along:

1. Batch size is sufficient size
2. Enough time has passed and a partial batch should be flushed

Your given example does not account for the second scenario. This can lead to some awkward behavior if you just never flush because you quit getting load.

Therefore I would recommend either looking into a library (e.g., [cloudfoundry/go-batching](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/go-batching)) or simply use channels, a Timer and a select statement.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        tasks := []string{}
        timer := time.NewTimer(time.Second) // Adjust this based on a reasonable user experience
        for {
            select {
            case <-timer.C:
                fmt.Println("Flush partial batch due to time")
                flush(tasks)
                tasks = nil
                timer.Reset(time.Second)
            case data := <-ch:
                tasks = append(tasks, data)

                // Reset the timer for each data point so that we only flush
                // partial batches when we stop receiving data.
                if !timer.Stop() {
                    <-timer.C
                }
                timer.Reset(time.Second)

                // Guard clause to for batch size
                if len(tasks) < 3 {
                    fmt.Println("Queue still too small")
                    continue
                }

                flush(tasks)
                tasks = nil // reset tasks
            }
        }
    }()

    ch <- "Msg 1"
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    ch <- "Msg 2"
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    ch <- "Msg 3"
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    ch <- "Msg 4"
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}

func flush(tasks []string) {
    // Guard against emtpy flushes
    if len(tasks) == 0 {
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Flush")
    for _, t := range tasks {
        fmt.Println(t)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be better to use mutexes or waitgroups so that a timer isn't required.

Comment: @dustinevan I don't think I understand what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: this is not perfectly objective, but go's concurrency constructs exist to allow developers to orchestrate systems where data flows via a reactive model. e.g. you do something when something needs to be done, rather than asking whether something needs to be done, and doing when the answer is yes. Using a timer is a polling model, rather than a reactive one.

Comment: Saw this again. Is the point to only take individual pieces of data as fast as the duration (in this case time.Second) will allow? When data is available from <-ch, it will append the task and then wait for 1 second. I don't feel like rate limiting is part of the question here.

Comment: It doesn't rate limit. The timer is to flush partial batches. If the channel is always receiving data, the timer never fires

Answer (score 2):

I can see how something that batches results could be useful. But it does require a custom solution. There are many ways to solve this problem--I tried using `Sync.WaitGroup` but it got messy. It seems like using a `sync.Mutex` to lock the batching function is the best way. But, when mutex is the nicest answer imo that should trigger a recheck of the design because, again imo, it should be the last option.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
)

func main() {

    ctx, canc := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    acc := NewAccumulator(4, ctx)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            acc.Write("hi")
        }
        canc()
    }()

    read := acc.ReadChan()
    for batch := range read {
        fmt.Println(batch)
    }
    fmt.Println("done")
}

type Accumulator struct {
    count    int64
    size     int
    in       chan string
    out      chan []string
    ctx      context.Context
    doneFlag int64
    mu   sync.Mutex
}

func NewAccumulator(size int, parentCtx context.Context) *Accumulator {
    a := &Accumulator{
        size: size,
        in:   make(chan string, size),
        out:  make(chan []string, 1),
        ctx:  parentCtx,
    }

    go func() {
        <-a.ctx.Done()
        atomic.AddInt64(&a.doneFlag, 1)
        close(a.in)
        a.mu.Lock()
        a.batch()
        a.mu.Unlock()
        close(a.out)
    }()
    return a
}

func (a *Accumulator) Write(s string) {
    if atomic.LoadInt64(&a.doneFlag) > 0 {
        panic("write to closed accumulator")
    }
    a.in <- s
    atomic.AddInt64(&a.count, 1)
    a.mu.Lock()
    if atomic.LoadInt64(&a.count) == int64(a.size) {
        a.batch()
    }
    a.mu.Unlock()
}

func (a *Accumulator) batch() {
    batch := make([]string, 0)
    for i := 0; i < a.size; i++ {
        msg := <-a.in
        if msg != "" {
            batch = append(batch, msg)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("batching", batch)
    a.out <- batch
    atomic.StoreInt64(&a.count, 0)
}

func (a *Accumulator) ReadChan() <-chan []string {
    return a.out
}
```

It probably would be best of just have a slice that accumulates strings and when that slice reaches some size, then you kick off some processing.